# Problems with AWS credentials when renewing Let's Encrypt certificates with certbot

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, certbot

I have 4 servers with Let's Encrypt HTTPS certificates which should renew with certbot. They were created with user `ubuntu` with the flags `--dns-route53`, `--dns-digitalocean` and `--dns-digitalocean-credentials` respectively. When I installed certbot, a file `/etc/cron.d/certbot` was created:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew
```

But, I think it runs from root, and the credentials for these flags expect user ubuntu. And I checked, they are not automatically renewed (except one certificate which was created without these flags). How do I configure these certificates to renew automatically?

To renew them manually, I can run `sudo certbot renew` from user `ubuntu`, and then type the password.

I think there is a problem with the `test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system` command, so I want to add this line to root crontab:

```
27 2-20/12 * * * perl -e 'sleep int(rand(1800))' && certbot -q renew
```

I found out that running only "`certbot -q renew`" as root is OK, but I need to change the settings from user `ubuntu` to `root`. And I'm using S3, I have a problem with AWS S3 credentials and Route 53 credentials - the server uses one of them instead of the other. Do you know how I configure S3 credentials to be used by S3 and Route 53 credentials to be used by Route 53?

I'm looking how to change `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` according to this page:
https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

But changing it only to certbot and not to S3.

I tried with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/root/.aws/config
certbot -q renew
```

But it doesn't work if the file `/root/.aws/credentials` is present. Only if I delete this file, I can run `certbot renew` successfully. But I need this file to backup my files to S3.

`/root/.aws/credentials` contains my credentials to S3, and `/root/.aws/config` contains my credentials to Route 53.

Comment: Are the servers EC2 instances? If yes, they why not instance profile to provide all the permissions needed for S3 or R53?

Comment: @Marcin No, they are hosted at DigitalOcean.

Comment: config and credentials are both required for the aws cli tool. If you are hosting DNS at AWS route53 then you shouldn't have to worry about the digital ocean stuff. Just --dns-route53 would do it.